# How to setup Websockets as datastream for apache flink

Tags: java, websocket, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i have built a nodejs backend that would send websockets to the frontend, i want to setup apache flink in the middle whereby it takes the websockets as stream and just listens until some condition applies on the data being sent, then it would send an alert.
now i'm not really sure if its feasible to set websockets as datastream, if not is there any alternatives to it?

i have tried this

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> dataStream = env
    .socketTextStream("localhost", 3000)
    .flatMap(new Splitter())
    .keyBy(value -> value.f0)
    .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5))
    .sum(1);

dataStream.print();
```

but it didn't work although my websocket server is up and running

Comment: If I recall correctly, a socketTextStream expects a line of text terminated with a carriage return.

Comment: Using Websockets implies that you're OK with no resilience (since there's no durable storage for whatever comes from the websocket). Do keep that in mind